# How to add a Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a fragment that contains a `TabLayout` View, but I keep getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.newTab()' on a null object reference
                                                                at ca.rev.revcore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
```

This is the layout I'm trying to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rev_tablayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/RevStyle_PlaceNewBagBttn">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tab1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

And this is how I'm trying to add it:

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.rev_tablayout);

 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Upload"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pics"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Vids"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Papers"));

 tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_publish_black_24dp);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_videocam_black_24dp);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_airplay_black_24dp);
```

What could I be missing?

Vielen dank im voraus.

Comment: give your full activity.java code

Comment: add complete code both java and xml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using fragment then. Change

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.rev_tablayout);
```

to

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rev_tablayout);
```

`view` is the object which will inflate your layout file and return view in `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Piyush, but what is view here? Sorry. I'm a complete ANdroid newbie.

Comment: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);` which inflate your layout and return view in `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: I really can't be thankful enough @Piyush. Been at this for so long. Thank you.

Comment: Nvm ! Wel come :)

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using fragment then. binding of controls like this in your oncreate view where you inflate your layout**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Override onCreateView() method in Fragment, and inflate the Fragment
>   layouts using LayoutInflater Class object and by pass­ing the
>   ViewGroup argu­ment which is the activity in which the frag­ment will
>   be embedded.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) your_View_OBJ.findViewById(R.id.rev_tablayout);
```

**Demo**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_name, container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rev_tablayout);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Tab Layout with id rev_tablayout in activity_main xml or is it in fragment's layout? please check where you are trying to access the tablayout.